# Prove $P(X<2<4X)=P(\frac{1}{2}<X<2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is  $P(X<2<4X)=P(\frac{1}{2}<X<2)$ ??

I came across a question that requires me  to find the probability that 2 lies between X and 4X. which is $P(X<2<4X)$ , so this was impossilbe for  me to evaluate using $F(x)$. The book explanation said "the trick is to write 
$$P(X<2<4X)=P(\frac{1}{2}<X<2)$$

Can anyone show me how the author made this statement, how did he convert  the LHS to RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$X < 2 < 4X \to \left\{ \begin{array}{l}X < 2\\2 < 4X \to X > \frac{1}{2}\end{array} \right.$$

Answer (score 2):

$X < 2 < 4X$ means "$X < 2$ and $2 < 4X$."

$\frac{1}{2} < X < 2$ means "$\frac{1}{2} < X$ and $X < 2$."

So all you need to do is check that the inequalities $2 < 4X$ and $\frac{1}{2} < X$ are equivalent. You can go from the first to the second by multiplying both sides of the inequality by $\frac{1}{4}$.